# Android Task vs. Activity - What are they "really"?

Tags: android, android-activity, task

I'm trying to understand Android Tasks vs. Activities "under the hood" for debugging (and my edification). Many other StackOverflow answers and the Android docs address the issue, in a *detailed but abstract way*. What are they *really*? My (maybe incorrect) theory follows:

(1) A "Task" is a multi-threaded Linux **process** and (2) an Activity is a  **thread** within that process to service the Activity.

Is this accurate or am I off-base?

UPDATE 8/21/19
Most of the answers so far do not address my question. They simply echo the descriptions of the abstractions in the Android Doc. I find it extremely unlikely that the Android Framework subsumes process management facilities already in the Linux kernel, e.g. processes, pthreads, etc. Rather IMHO  Android Activities and Tasks are wrappers around the Linux functions. I'm pretty sure that (1) in my theory is correct, but I'm not sure about (2). Does anybody truly understand what's going on under the hood of these abstractions?

Comment: "A "Task" is a multi-threaded Linux process" -- no. A task is closer to a Web browser tab. It is a record of a back stack of activities. "and an Activity is a thread within that process to service the Activity" -- no. An activity is a Java object that represents the primary unit of Android UI.

Comment: Here is the explanation of task https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

`Task`s are **just stacks** that hold `Activities`.  Also `Activities` just hold the UI and and become a part of that Stack. Source: 
[Tasks and the Back Stack (Android Development Patterns)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvIlVsXxXmY)

Same applies to `Fragment`s inside `Activities`. Just like they are part of the `Activity` backstack, Activities are part of the stack called `Task`(s).

When you press the overview button or home button, what you see is not the `Activity` but a `Task` with the latest `Activity` on top. Source for that: 
[Single Activity, why , when and how.](https://youtu.be/2k8x8V77CrU?t=1583)

So to answer your question:

> Is this accurate or am I off-base?

That's a concept which is used in Linux, not Android specific related (even tho Android is Linux). So different concept, same naming.

Answer (score -1):

An Activity is not a Thread.  At all.  An Activity is a controller for a UI.  Basically its the code that coordinates a screen or a workflow.  It does not have a thread attached to it (but some functions are guaranteed to run on the main thread when called by the framework (and you shouldn't call them directly)).

A Task.  There's AsyncTask that's basically a wrapper around Thread with pre and post functions running on the UI thread (and optional periodic update messages to the UI).

THere's another Task that's just a set of activities that you can navigate back through with the back button.  Think of it as the user's path through your app.  But you'll work with this concept very little, its mostly automated.